# Bukkit / Spigotplugin - Remove entry from config

Tags: java, plugins, config, bukkit

I'm working on a Bukkit / Spigotplugin which allows users to vote for things.
The plugin uses a config. I want to remove an entry but it doesn't work.
What I found on Google:

```
getConfig().set("your.value", null);
```

what I implemented:

```
int i = id;
while(getConfig().contains("ThingsYouCanVoteFor." + (i + 1)))
{
    getConfig().set("ThingsYouCanVoteFor." + Integer.toString(i) + ".name", getConfig().getString("ThingsYouCanVoteFor." + Integer.toString(i + 1) + ".name"));
    getConfig().set("ThingsYouCanVoteFor." + Integer.toString(i) + ".votes", getConfig().getInt("ThingsYouCanVoteFor." + Integer.toString(i + 1) + ".votes"));
    i++;
}
getConfig().set("ThingsYouCanVoteFor." + Integer.toString(i + 1), null);
saveConfig();
sender.sendMessage("§aRemoved ID " + id);
```

how the config looks:

```
ThingsYouCanVoteFor:
  0:
    name: Build a bridge
    votes: 0
  1:
    name: Kill the owner
    votes: 2
  2:
    name: Vote for something other
    votes: 1
  3:
    name: Remove all banned peoples inventory
    votes: 0
  4:
    name: Teleport to others home
    votes: 0
  5:
    name: Dig a hole in the air
    votes: 0
  6:
    name: Shutdown the internet
    votes: 0
PeopleWhoVoted:
- Gamingwelle
- BDevGWAdmin
- Sllikson
OpenForVoting: false
```

how it should look like when I use "/voteadmin remove 3":

```
ThingsYouCanVoteFor:
  0:
    name: Build a bridge
    votes: 0
  1:
    name: Kill the owner
    votes: 2
  2:
    name: Vote for something other
    votes: 1
  3:
    name: Teleport to others home
    votes: 0
  4:
    name: Dig a hole in the air
    votes: 0
  5:
    name: Shutdown the internet
    votes: 0
PeopleWhoVoted:
- Gamingwelle
- BDevGWAdmin
- Sllikson
OpenForVoting: false
```

how it looks:

```
ThingsYouCanVoteFor:
  0:
    name: Build a bridge
    votes: 0
  1:
    name: Kill the owner
    votes: 2
  2:
    name: Vote for something other
    votes: 1
  3:
    name: Teleport to others home
    votes: 0
  4:
    name: Dig a hole in the air
    votes: 0
  5:
    name: Shutdown the internet
    votes: 0
  6:
    name: Shutdown the internet
    votes: 0
PeopleWhoVoted:
- Gamingwelle
- BDevGWAdmin
- Sllikson
OpenForVoting: false
```

using

```
getConfig().getConfigurationSection("ThingsYouCanVoteFor").getKeys(false).remove(i + 1)
```

doesn't work either.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I believe you got you desired config and the actual config wrong. They're not differente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remove the value in a path using:

```
config.set(pathToRemove, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

[ConfigurationSection](https://jd.bukkit.org/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html)'s set methods changed the value like you want, however when saving the config it will override all current values. This means you have to edit/specify every single value if you want to keep them or they'll be lost.
To instead only need to have to edit a single value, I use an array.

The array is there to keep temporary data in, you seem to need an object holding `String name` and `int votes`, I call this object `VoteData`.

When server starts, load config and fill the array with the result. This allows us to remove objects or modify the array on runtime without touching the config file, improving performance.

```
private void loadConfig() {

    voteDataArray = new ArrayList<VoteData>();
    YamlConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(yourConfigFile);

    ConfigurableSection section = config.getConfigurableSection("ThingsYouCanVoteFor");
    if(section == null) {
        Bukkit.getLogger().warn("ConfigSection ThingsYouCanVoteFor doesn't exist");
        return;
    }

    for(String num : section.getKeys(false)) {

        String name = section.getString(num + ".name");
        int votes = section.getDouble(num + ".votes");

        voteDataArray.add(new VoteData(name, votes));

    }
}
```

When server closes or whenever you want, save the config with the array's content by looping through `config.getKeys(false)` and setting the node to your data's values.

```
private void saveConfig() {

    YamlConfiguration config = new YamlConfiguration();

    int num = 1;
    for(VoteData data : voteDataArray) {
        config.set("ThingsYouCanVoteFor." + num + ".name", data.getName());
        config.set("ThingsYouCanVoteFor." + num + ".votes", data.getVotes());
        num++;
    }

    try {
        config.save(yourConfigFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now when you need to use the data in the plugin, use the array instead of the config. And when you want to remove something, simply remove from the array.

Comment: But what if I want to remove something wich was allready in the config when it was loaded from the file?